Clean way to configure Debian package prometheus-node-exporter
I want to configure Prometheus Node Exporter installed through Debian package prometheus-node-exporter
There is no configuration file attached to this package.
The only way I have found is to modify the file

/etc/default/prometheus-node-exporter

with
ARGS="--web.config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"

Then for the configuration itself I've defined
basic_auth_users:
  prometheus: SECRET_PASSWORD

into

/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml

Is there a cleanest way to do it ? I cannot imagine Debian has made a package without configuration file when it's possible to do it.

I think you need to address this question to Debian maintainers.
